# How to build Box2D Testbed (ArchLinux)

Tags: box2d, archlinux

I've `svn checkout`ed the source code, made some changes so that running `cmake` in the /Box2D/ directory works properly, but when I `make`, the linker says it cannot find the library `-lglew`. The `HelloWorld` examples builds fine, but the `Testbed` isn't built correctly. `ld` is trying to find the library `/usr/lib/libglew.so` or something to that effect but it's actually called `/usr/lib/libGLEW.so`. Creating symbolic links to the lowercase version still turned up with errors. I could not get `yaourt` to install `premake 4.4` correctly, and I see that the Box2D package in AUR is just the library and no testbed.

How do I build this testbed?

Comment: Maybe you could try the slightly older version (r278) that was not so demanding on graphical display capability. The physics engine features themselves have barely changed.

Comment: I'm actually following your tutorial to learn it! And yeah, I asked my friend for help and he just built an earlier version and it went flawlessly... Great tutorial by the way, way better than the user manual.

Comment: Is this still valid? If no then please put resolution in answers.